# Load local reports dynamically on Report Viewer Control - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parameters, reporting

I started using the microsoft report viewer + their report designer its pretty good i'd say. I have one problem i can't solve though.

I want to have one form with the report viewer control and just send to this form the name of the report and the parameters it needs, and i suppose the data source ( i need to provide the data source each time i load a report? cause i assigned it inside the report designer).

Does anyone have an example on how to do that? I did some research but i didnt find something useful.

Now i am loading the reports like the example below..

```cs
private void ReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDataSource dt = new  ReportDataSource("Customer2",bindingSource1);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dt);
    ReportParameter pm = new ReportParameter("id");
    pm.Values.Add("1");
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(pm);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: I don't see anyplace in your code where you tell the report viewer what report file to use.

Comment: i set the report file in the designer.

Comment: Is there more than one report file? When you stated "send to this form the name of the report" I assumed you meant different report files. Without specifying the report file in the report viewer the report viewer is always going to use the report file set in the designer.

Comment: yes there are more than one depending of the form i use.

Comment: Then you MUS?T provide a report file name to the report view control.

Comment: ok but i don't think this is relevant with my question..

Comment: With the exception of adding the report name, the code you show should work. I've used something similar to that in the past. Are you getting an error? What are your results. What is not working?